# SQL nesting join to same data table

Tags: sql, join, nested

I hope that I formulated tittle right.

I have simple data table **(blog_comments):**

> 1.id
>
> 2.post_id
>
> 3.comment
>
> 4.date
>
> 5.addedby
>
> 6.comment_id(for replies.)

My idea is all known for everyone. I want to display comments and replies for each comment, ordered by upvotes.

I am possible to display comments, that are not replies, but can't manage to show replies.

At this moment, this code: don't show even simple comments. If I remove `reply.*` it shows simple comments.

```
public function getBlogCommentList($post_id){
    try{

        $sortby = "SELECT c.*, reply.*, u.id as user_id, u.username as username, u.image as profile_image,
            SUM(CASE WHEN r.upvote=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as upvotes,
            SUM(CASE WHEN r.downvote=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as downvotes
            FROM cb_community.blog_comments c
            LEFT JOIN cb_users.users u ON u.id = c.addedby
            LEFT JOIN cb_community.blog_comment_ratings r ON r.comment_id = c.id
            LEFT JOIN (SELECT rc.*, ru.id as user_id, ru.username as rusername, ru.image as rprofile_image,
                SUM(CASE WHEN rr.upvote=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as rupvotes,
                SUM(CASE WHEN rr.downvote=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as rdownvotes
                FROM cb_community.blog_comments rc
                LEFT JOIN cb_users.users ru ON ru.id = rc.addedby
                LEFT JOIN cb_community.blog_comment_ratings rr ON rr.comment_id = rc.id
                WHERE rc.post_id = $post_id AND rc.comment_id is not null GROUP BY rc.id ORDER BY rupvotes DESC) reply ON reply.comment_id = c.id
            WHERE c.post_id = $post_id AND c.comment_id is null GROUP BY c.id ORDER BY upvotes DESC";



    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("$sortby");
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

        $blog_comments = array();

    foreach($result as $post){
            $blog_comments[] = $post;
        }

    return $blog_comments;

  }
  catch(PDOException $e)
  {
    echo $e->getMessage();
  }
}
```

Edit with only **blog_comments** table:

```
        $sortby = "SELECT c.*
                FROM cb_community.blog_comments c
                LEFT JOIN (SELECT rc.*
                    FROM cb_community.blog_comments rc
                    WHERE rc.post_id = $post_id AND rc.comment_id is not null GROUP BY rc.id) reply ON reply.comment_id = c.id
                WHERE c.post_id = $post_id AND c.comment_id is null GROUP BY c.id";
```

I don't know if I'm even on right flow. I want to display all comments and for each comment display all it's replies.

Comment: I'm totally confused.  Do you have a simple table?  Or do you have a bunch of tables that you need to join together?  Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I edited post with simple data table. But in reality I have a this table that I need to join 2x times and bunch of different other tables.

Answer (score 1):

Because you want to include the Reply comment text, it effectively means that you cannot group by the original comment because each reply comment will be unique and therefore cannot rollup.

If you want the total number of up votes for all replies then you need to remove the reply text from the columns returned. The only columns from the reply part should be the SUM(UpVotes) and SUM(DownVotes) and then group these by the original comment columns (and related User and Comment Up/Down Votes columns that are static for the original column).

If you just want to display the original comment and each of the replies with the final data set ordered by the original comment and then each of the replies in order of UpVotes then you need:

```
SELECT c.id as CommentId,
       c.comment as CommentText,
       r.comment as ReplyText,
       v.upvotes as UpVotes,
       v.downvotes as DownVotes
FROM blog_comments c
LEFT JOIN blog_comments r ON c.id = r.commentid
LEFT JOIN blog_comments_rating v ON r.id = v.commentid
WHERE c.commentid IS NULL
ORDER BY c.id, v.upvotes ASC
```